# last month to last 10 month pandas datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How to create two variables.

- 1 - variable **last month**
- 2 - variable **past 10 month**

Like the date that represents TODAY - 10 months, so for example:`2020/02/05 - 10 months =  2019/04/05`.

my code:

```
import datime

# 1- last month
month = datetime.datetime.now().month
year = datetime.datetime.now().year

last_month = f"{year}/{month-1}/01"
>>>
"2020/01/05"



# Past 12 months
past_10month = datetime.datetime.today()
past_10month = f"{past_10month -285}"
>>>
# DO NOT WORK

# EXPECTED RESULT:
# "2019/04/05"
```

Comment: you need date of last month and last year month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

dt = datetime.now()
last_month = (dt - relativedelta(months=1)).date()
last_year = (dt - relativedelta(months=10)).date()
```

Output:

```
2020-01-05
2019-04-05
```

Comment: @Peter simply change `months=value`